# Llamar a un ArrayList creado en otra clase

Tags: java, array

Estoy tratando de hacer un pequeño proyecto, pero necesito declarar 1 ArrayList en una clase aparte de donde los estaré manipulando. Cuando trato de llamar al ArrayList en otra clase, no me funciona porque no lo lee, adjunto codigo de las dos clases

Clase donde se crea el array:

```
public class DataAnimales {
    
    ArrayList <Mamiferos> Mamifero = new ArrayList <Mamiferos>();   
    
    public ArrayList<Mamiferos> llamadaMamiferos() {
         return Mamifero;
    }
}
```

Clase donde lo quiero ejecutar

```
import java.util.*;
public class Mamiferos extends Animales{
    String inputMov;
    String TipoReproduccion;
    Scanner Leer = new Scanner (System.in);

    public Mamiferos() {
        super();
        TipoReproduccion = "Mamifero";
    }

    public Mamiferos(String I, String R, String G, String NA, double a, double p, int Pr) {
        super(I, R , G, NA, a, p, Pr);
        TipoReproduccion = "Mamifero";
    }
    
    public void FiltroMovimiento() {
        System.out.print("Dime que tipo de movimiento quieres filtrar (Tierra, Mar o Aire): ");
        inputMov = Leer.nextLine();
        for(int s=0;s<         ;s++){           
            
        }
    }
}
```

En este caso, ese espacio en blanco dentro del for es donde lo quiero ejecutar, ya que quiero recorrerlo para que busque un dato en concreto.

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver la etiqueta `Javascript` con `Java`? Haz clic en [edit] y quita la etiqueta no relevante. Por otro lado, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so] y te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour].

Comment: @MauricioContreras acabo de eliminar la etiqueta JavaScript como pediste, y de paso aprovecharé para leer lo que me recomendaste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer uso del `ArrayList` declarado en la clase *DataAnimales* ,debes instanciar un objeto nuevo de esa clase para hacer uso del metodo **llamadaMamiferos()** el cual te devuelve el array que necesitas..

```
public class Mamiferos extends Animales{
    String inputMov;
    String TipoReproduccion;
    Scanner Leer = new Scanner (System.in);
    DataAnimales dataAnimales=new DataAnimales();
    ArrayList <Mamiferos> nombreDelArray = dataAnimales.llamadaMamiferos();
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ahora si entiendo como hacerlo.